# Scaling of external monitor with xrandr [Ubuntu 20.04.1]

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

thank you in advance for any help. Currently, I am trying to use an external monitor (, which has a resolution of 1920x1080) together with my laptop screen (, which has a 4k display). Currently, my external display is on the right of my laptop screen.

Issue: At the moment the scaling is wrong on the external display (graphics get rendered much bigger than they actually are).

I have tried to use xrandr by following several forum posts and ended up by this command:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --mode 3840x2160 --output DP-1-1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 2x2 --pos 3840x0 --panning 3840x2160+3840+0 --right-of eDP-1-1
```

This command results in an error message regarding bad match relating to the panning attribute. See below.

`Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes) Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR) Minor opcode of failed request:  29 (RRSetPanning) Serial number of failed request:  37 Current serial number in output stream:  37`

The output for my displays is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 7680 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+  59.98    59.97  
   3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1-1 connected 3840x2160+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       66.67    60.00    59.95    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

As I tried really many things, I really need your help. Thank you again. :)